# Read subelement of node values of an xml in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, treenode

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to read an xml file which contains a list of teams and its members. I want to access a member name.

```
-<xml>
    -<teams>
        -<team>
            -<members>
               -<member1>
                   <style>Name1</style>
               </member1>
               -<member2>
                   <style>Name2</style>
               </member2>
               -<member3>
                   <style>Name3</style>
               </member3>
             </members>
        -</team>
        -<team>
        …
        -<team>
        -</team>
        …
        -<team>
        -</team>
    -</teams>
-</xml>
```

I use the codes below to get member name:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
    tree = ET.parse(infile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root[0]:
        for node in child:
            if node.tag=="members":
                for _member in node.iter("style"):
                    print(_member.text)
```

These codes solve problem partially. Indeed, It is much efficient to access the tag member1 directly. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` has a limited XPath support but it is enough in this case:

```
for name in root.findall(".//team/members/*/style"):
    print(name.text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> 
>>> for name in root.findall(".//team/members/*/style"):
...     print(name.text)
... 
Name1
Name2
Name3
```